# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Tags: asp.net

I'm receiving this error from one of our web pages: "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array".

This is the stack trace from my exception:

```
at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)     
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)     
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState)     
at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState)     
at System.Web.UI.SessionPageStatePersister.Load()
```

Code behind .cs:

```
protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
{
    get
    {
        return new SessionPageStatePersister(Page);
    }
}
```

What would cause this error?

Comment: What's the exact string being processed?

Comment: I'm not author for this. Moreover i'm trying to fix this issue. server controls are passing as page. So what is the root cause for this.

Comment: Or is there any way to reproduce by sample code, so this would have help me to fix this error.

Comment: You should be able to attach the debugger and see what's inside that string variable.

Answer (score 2):

This error is thrown if the Base64 string has a space in it. I have seen this kind of incorrectly encoded Base64 strings being passed around from SagePay (used to be Protx).

Its because Request.QueryString[] decodes the string and treats the + (a valid character in a base64 string) as a space (which is correct as urlencoding treats + as a space.

I have written about this in the following article:

- [Why asp.net accidentally corrupts your base64 encoded strings if you pass them as a query string (its nothing personal)](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/10/why-aspnet-accidentally-corrupts-your.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem during decryption, the issue sometimes happens when there is a space in an Encrypted String, what I did was replace the space with a +

```
cryptedString = cryptedString.Replace(" ", "+");
```

This might be your issue as well.